# Query. Select from table where count of objects > n

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have got table "**Cars**" with fields *ModelName,Maker,Year,Price* and table "**Maker**" with field *Name*. 
I need Linq to Sql query where I can select all makers where count of models > *n*.

I tried it with:

```
Data.ItemsSource = (from m in db.GetTable<Maker>()
                    where (from c in db.GetTable<Car>() 
                           where c.Maker == m.Name 
                           select c).Count() > 1
                    select m.Name);
```

But have no results. How can I implement that?

UPD. 
Table Car code

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Car] (
    [CarId]     INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ModelName] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Equipment] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Year]      INT           NULL,
    [Price]     INT           NULL,
    [Cathegory] NCHAR (20)    DEFAULT ('Sedan') NOT NULL,
    [Maker]     NCHAR (20)    DEFAULT ('Toyota') NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CarId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Car_ToCatheg] FOREIGN KEY ([Cathegory]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Catheg] ([Name]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Car_ToMaker] FOREIGN KEY ([Maker]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Maker] ([Name]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Class Car

```
 [Table(Name = "Car")]
    public class Car
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
        public int CarId { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string ModelName { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string Equipment { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public int Year { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public int Price { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string Maker { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string Cathegory { get; set; }

        public Car()
        { }
        public Car(string modelName, string equipment, int year, int price, string cath, string carmaker, int id = -1)
        {
            ModelName = modelName;
            Equipment = equipment;
            Year = year;
            Price = price;
            Maker = carmaker;
            Cathegory = cath;
            CarId = id;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ModelName + " " + Equipment + " " + Year + " " + Maker + " " + Price + " " + Cathegory;

        }
```

Table Maker code

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Maker] (
    [Name] NCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Name] ASC)
);
```

Class Maker

```
[Table(Name = "Maker")]
public class Maker
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Seems like you'd want `c.MakerId == m.Id` or something along those lines unless `Maker` is just the name of the maker.  Also you should be able to use Navigation properties assuming you have foreign key relationships between the tables and the entities are setup to correctly take advantage of them.  Can you share the code for the entities in question?  Also are you really using Linq-To-Sql instead of EF?

Answer (score 0):

This should give you maker names with respective count.

```
var Results = from c in db.GetTable<Car>() 
group c by c.Maker into cg
join m in db.GetTable<Maker>() on cg.FirstOrDefault().Maker equals m.Name
where cg.Count() > 1
select new 
{
    MakerName = m.Name,
    Count = cg.Count()
};
```

Comment: `cg.Key` should be same as `cg.FirstOrDefault().Maker`, but `join` is redundant since you aren't referencing any other fields from `Maker`.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually meant the number of *`Cars`* for each `Maker.Name`, you can just group on `Car.Maker` and the `Maker` table is unneeded:

```
Data.ItemsSource = from c in db.GetTable<Car>()
                   group c by c.Maker into cg
                   where cg.Count() > 1
                   select cg.Key;
```

If models are actually independant of `Year` and `Price`, then you need to just count `ModelName`s:

```
var models = (from c in db.GetTable<Car>()
             select new { c.Maker, c.ModelName }).Distinct();

Data.ItemsSource = from c in models
                   group c by c.Maker into cg
                   where cg.Count() > 1
                   select cg.Key;
```

Comment: How can I get values from cg.Key? I wanted to show result in Datagrid, but it only shows empty rows

Comment: @FeoJun I am not sure I understand - `cg.Key` is going to be each `c.Maker` so it is just the Maker names, just like your sample.